# Deserialize python pickle file from C#

Tags: python, c#, numpy, deserialization, pickle

I'm trying to read a python generated pickle file from C# and encounter a run-time error

> Crashed with PickleException:
>
> expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct).
> This happens when an unsupported/unregistered class is being unpickled that requires construction arguments.
>
> Fix it by registering a custom IObjectConstructor for this class.

Tried following code. How can I register a custom IObjectConstructor
to deal with np.core.multiarray type in C#?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Razorvine.Pickle;
using NumSharp;
using NumSharp.Extensions;
using Numpy;

// To learn more about cTrader Automate visit our Help Center:
// https://help.ctrader.com/ctrader-automate

    // Load the pickle file into a byte array
    //byte[] pickleData = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/svm_model.pkl");
            
    // Load the model from file
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:/svm_model.pkl", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        Unpickler unpickler = new Unpickler();
        object obj = unpickler.load(stream);

        // Register custom constructors for NumSharp.NDArray and numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct
        unpickler.RegisterConstructor("numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct", new NumpyReconstructConstructor());
        unpickler.RegisterConstructor("numpy.ndarray", new NumpyArrayConstructor());


    // obj should be a scikit-learn model instance that you can use for predictions
    // For example:
    var x = Numpy.np.array(new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 });
        var y = (double)obj.GetType().GetMethod("predict").Invoke(obj, new object[] { x });
    }
        
    public class NumpyArrayConstructor : IObjectConstructor
    {
        public object construct(object[] args)
        {
            // Extract the typecode, shape, and dtype from the arguments
            string typecode = (string)args[0];
            int[] shape = (int[])args[1];
            string dtype = (string)args[2];
    
            // Create a new NumSharp array with the specified typecode, shape, and dtype
            return new NDArray(Array.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(dtype), shape), shape);
        }
    }
    // Define a custom constructor for the numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct class
    class NumpyReconstructConstructor : IObjectConstructor
    {
        public object construct(object[] args)
        {
            // Construct the object using the provided arguments
            return new Numpy.np.core.multiarray._reconstruct((string)args[0], (int)args[1], (string)args[2]);
        }
    }
}
```